# Best .NET graphics library for 3D sphere drawing?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics

I am going to be making an application that lets users input several parameters for a bowling ball layout, and then show what that layout would look like on the ball.  I have found some good resources for sphere math, so if I have a sphere whose center is (0,0,0), I will be able to get the values of the points I need on the surface of the ball.  What I will need to do is have the library create:

- A sphere
- Mark points on the surface of the sphere
- Draw lines connecting the points on the sphere (arcs along a great circle - in other words, the shortest distance across the surface of the sphere)
- ***Super duper bonus*** Actually be 3D, so the user could pan, zoom, rotate.

Basically, I want to calculate the points, tell the library which ones to draw and which ones to connect with which colors, and then sit back and watch the kudos roll in.

---

I'd like to use .NET 2.0 and WinForms if possible...

Answer (score 2):

If you're gonna be using WPF I recommend you use [Perspective](http://www.codeplex.com/perspective) or [3DTools](http://www.codeplex.com/3DTools). They're both easy to use and do the job fine.

If I had to recommend only one I would go with Perspective, at the time I used it it was easier and had more features, but it's been a long time so you should probably see for yourself.

Comment: Any recommendations if I'm just doing winforms?

Comment: Sorry, no experience with 3D in winforms. When I needed to do 3D I had to use Managed DirectX to accomplish what I wanted in winforms, I found it too complicated and ended up using WPF which is easier IMHO. You could host a WPF control in winforms but it's probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you use GLUT, you could just have the library draw the sphere for you without you having to figure out the points.

Comment: Any recommendations for a managed library?

Comment: Hmm, I figured somewhere out in the wild are managed wrappers for OpenGL and GLUT, but Google search comes up with spotty answers. This looks decent for OpenGL in C#: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/openGL/sharpgl.aspx but to find GLUT on top of this would be ideal for you to draw spheres easily.

Answer (score 1):

I found the OpenGL part of the [Tao Framework](http://www.taoframework.com/) quite capable. It provides raw OpenGL bindings, as well as GLUT and GLFW - as a beginner, I found GLFW much easier to use for my simple needs than GLUT. It comes with decent documentation on GLFW and samples.

Be aware though that these libraries create a 3d "view" that covers the entire window, so adding standard winforms UI may not be straightforward. That's not something I've tried. There were however some samples that showed simple GUIs.